# error: expected primary-expression before ';' token

Tags: c++, exception

I get the error

```
error: expected primary-expression before ';' token
```

when I try to compile the following code. What is the problem?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class MyException : public std::invalid_argument{};

int main() {
    try {
        throw MyException; //here is the problem
    }
    catch (...){
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried also this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
using namespace std;

class MyException : public std::invalid_argument{};

int main() {
    try {
        throw MyException(); //here is the problem
    }
    catch (...){
    }

    return 0;
}
```

but then I get another error

```
main.cpp: In constructor ‘MyException::MyException()’:
main.cpp:6:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument()’
main.cpp:6:7: note: candidates are:
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/stdexcept:86:14: note: std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(const string&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/stdexcept:86:14: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/stdexcept:83:9: note: std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument(const std::invalid_argument&)
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../../include/c++/4.7.2/stdexcept:83:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:27: note: synthesized method ‘MyException::MyException()’ first required here
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of problems;

- The base class `std::invalid_argument` doesn't have a default constructor, you need to pass it a string.
- You need to pass parameters to your exception constructor, or at least invoke with `()`

In other words, something like this;

```cpp
class MyException : public std::invalid_argument {
public:
   MyException(const std::string& message) : std::invalid_argument(message) {}
};

int main() {
    try {
        throw MyException("bop"); //here is the problem
    }
...
```

Comment: I just add the answers from another forum I discussed this problem at. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/107778/

Answer (score 7):

You need to create an actual object to throw:

```
throw MyException();
```

Without parentheses `MyException` is just the type, it doesn't create an object.

Comment: I tried what you said but then I get another error (see my post).

Answer (score 6):

`MyException` is the name of a class, not an object. You have to either create a new instance of the class during the throw, like this:

```
throw MyException();
```

or throw a previously defined version of the class, like this:

```
myException except;
throw except;
```

Note that the second option would be silly in this example, as it creates a pointless temporary, but in a more complex situation could be useful (that is, if you had values and/or methods in the `MyException` class).

Answer (score 0):

Try putting something like this:

```
    try{
        MyException excption;
        excption = /*...*/;
        throw excption;
        delete excption; //optional to delete excption once done with it
    catch(/*...*/)
    {
    //...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your main method

```
int main() 
{  
   try {  
          throw MyException; //here is the problem  
   }  
   catch (...){      
   }  
   return 0;  
}
```

Solution:

```
int main() 
{  
   try {
          MyException e;
          throw e; //problem solved    
   }  
   catch (...){      
   }  
   return 0;  
}
```

Explanation: You see MyException is a class. You can throw an object of the class.